# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.mycare.OtherClass

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have looked at a few other answers for similar problems but don't understand why mine isn't working.
In my firebase database, I have a list of users that have different information under them. I would like to retrieve information from a current userId to recyclerview.

**My code  looks like:**

```
  DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference databaseStatus = rootRef.child("other");
    String uid = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    databaseStatus.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot : ds.getChildren()) {

                    OtherClass otherClass = dSnapshot.getValue(OtherClass.class);
                    Log.d("Show", otherClass.getOname() == null ? "" : otherClass.getOname());
                    list.add(otherClass);
                }

                adapter = new ShowOtherDetails.OtherAdapter(ShowOtherDetails.this, list);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

which gives me this error :

```
  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.mycare.OtherClass
```

firebase data structure looks like this:

[image]

Please, can someone help me out?

Comment: your snapshot value is giving you a string value.

Comment: remove the random id under your userid

Comment: it's push Id to store entries from the same user as unique. because 1 user can add multiple data to their id and I want each data to be unique and not override the previous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

When saving do this:

```
    String key = databaseStatus.child(uid).push().getKey()
```

so you will be able to get the key.

---

then add the key as a child when retrieving here in the first method

```
databaseStatus.child(uid).child(key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

   @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {



                OtherClass otherClass = snapshot.getValue(OtherClass.class);
                Log.d("Show", otherClass.getOname() == null ? "" : otherClass.getOname());
                list.add(otherClass);
            }
```

Remove the for loop `for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren())`

Or do this:

```
    databaseStatus.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {

            for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot : ds.getChildren()) {

                String date=dataSnapshot.child("date").getValue().toString();
  String detail=dataSnapshot.child("detail").getValue().toString();
  String email=dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
  String id=dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue().toString()
   //and so on
            }
```

Comment: it gives me null values

Comment: yes remove the random id as I said in the comment above. The random id under the userid, its not needed. As the userid alone will identify the record

Comment: is there any other way?  because  I want each data to be unique

Comment: sry for the long response. Yes, I try your 2nd solution, and it worked for me.thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
i hope its work, Try this

 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                        String date= ds.child("date").getValue(String.class);
                        String detail= ds.child("detail").getValue(String.class);
                        String email= ds.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                        String id= ds.child("id").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("TAG", date+ " / "+detail+" / "+email+" / "+id);
                        OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass(date,detail,email,id);
                        listdata.add(otherClass);

                    }

                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adpter);
                    adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
```